# How do I apply check_markup() as Twig filter?

Tags: 8, theming

I am trying to modify output in my twig file. In D7, I was able modify data in my array with this

```
check_markup($tweet->text, 'full_html');
```

and I see that this function still exists in D8. However, I'm not sure how I would use this in a filter in twig. This is what I have so far:

```
{% for tweet in params.tweets %}
<div class="tweet-wrapper">
<div class="tweet-profile-image">
    <img src='{{ tweet.user.profile_image_url }}'/>
</div>
<div class='tweet-text'>
    <!--check_markup($tweet->text, 'full_html');-->
    {{ tweet.text }}
</div>


</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I actually tried to do this before I sent it to the template as well, but it didn't change anything:

```
 foreach($tweets as $tweet) {
  $tweet->text = check_markup($tweet->text, 'full_html');
  $cleanTweets[] = $tweet;
}
dpm($tweets);
$params = array('tweets' => $cleanTweets);
$tweet_template = array('#theme' => 'twitter_pull_tweet_listing', '#params' => $params);
return $tweet_template;
```

What I'm trying to do here is make drupal create links for web links in the twitter tweet text. This worked fine for me in D7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, what is the motivation here? Are you getting double escaping or something? Providing more background information may help to get you a better answer.

Before we get too much further, relying on a certain configuration of the `full_html` text format seems like it's not a good solution. For example, to get the below to work for automatically creating links for this scenario, I had to enable **Convert URLs into links** in the `full_html` text format.

If you take a look at the [documentation for `check_markup()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21filter%21filter.module/function/check_markup/8) you'll see this note:

> Note: this function should only be used when filtering text for use elsewhere than on a rendered HTML page. If this is part of a HTML page, then a renderable array with a #type 'processed_text' element should be used instead of this, because that will allow cache tags to be set and bubbled up, assets to be loaded and #post_render_cache callbacks to be associated. In other words: if you are presenting the filtered text in a HTML page, the only way this will be presented correctly, is by using the 'processed_text' element.

So based on that I think what you may want to do is in your block build method create a 'processed_text' element (render array):

```
foreach ($tweets as $tweet) {
  $cleanTweets[] = array(
    '#type' => 'processed_text',
    '#text' => $tweet->text,
    // Relying on the full_html text format to do certain things is probably
    // not a good idea.
    '#format' => 'full_html',
    // Potentially add keys for #filter_types_to_skip and #langcode.
  );
}
$params = array('tweets' => $cleanTweets);
return array('#theme' => 'twitter_pull_tweet_listing', '#params' => $params);
```

Then you can do this in your Twig template (`twitter-pull-tweet-listing.html.twig`):

```
{% for tweet in params.tweets %}
  …
  {{ tweet }}
  …
{% endfor %}
```

To relate this to Drupal 7, that Twig template code would be roughly equivalent to running `render()` on each array element (individual render array) in the `$cleanTweets` array.

If you're more interested in creating an actual Twig filter, the Twig documentation has [some information on that](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#filters), and [Symfony has some very comprehensive documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) that matches up with how you would [create a Twig extension in Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/node/1831138#twig-extensions).

Comment: Great answer, but I wouldn't re-assign the render array structure to $tweet->text, that overwrites the existing data, better pass it as a separate array or part of a bigger render array structure to the template.

Comment: @Berdir - I agree 100%! Feel free to edit the code.

Comment: @Cottser - Yes, I will be presenting this on an html page. I created a twitter pull module which creates a twitter block of twitter tweets. The tweet string contained a string representation of the link to the tweet, so I wanted to make sure that it was automatically wrapped with a <a> tag. Is this a security issue? I did it in D7. Second - I looked here https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/8 and I don't see 'proccessed_text' as a valid option. Is your code correct?

Comment: @user1015214 - The Form API documentation is manually maintained (not auto-generated) so it's out of date in several areas with regard to Drupal 8. If you look at `check_markup()` in D8 it's partially a render array builder which uses `'#type' => 'processed_text'`.

Comment: @Cottser - I tried using the processed text element as you suggested, with the code above, and it didn't change anything. Would you have an idea why? Do I need any other code besides for what you posted above?

Comment: @user1015214 - tough to say, can you maybe post a gist with some code?

Comment: @Cottser - here is the gist for the block class - https://gist.github.com/jesrig/49918d6dac83d698ec42 and this is the gist for the twig file - https://gist.github.com/jesrig/83e247b6f54ff57de60a

Comment: @user1015214 - thanks! I threw together a module on my local D8 install and I suspect all you need to do is print `{{ tweet }}` instead of `{{ tweet.text }}` in your template. I also updated the answer to add some more information. Here's what I ran: https://gist.github.com/Cottser/4374c2c8c9ee1bc14445

Comment: @Cottser - I Tried that and still nothing. The links in the tweet still show up as text instead of tweets. Also, with the code you provided, it wouldn't actually allow me to also display the image with tweet.user.profile_image_url. Have you been able to view your code working properly?

Comment: @user1015214 - `tweet` is a render array, you can't drill into it like that. It sounds like you'll want to restructure the data going into your Twig template so that `tweet` contains both the render array that renders the tweet text and any other information. Please note that I also updated the answer to indicate relying that relying on the configuration of the `full_html` text format for auto-linking is problematic (especially because it's off by default!).