# How to escape markup with check_markup in a twig template?

Tags: theming, 8

I am getting following error in drupal 8 :

The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Twig_Error_Syntax: Unknown "check_markup" function.

Twig template line :

```
{% set featured_portfolio_text = check_markup(featured_portfolio_array['field_portfolio_link_text']['#items'][0]['value'],'full_html') %}
```

Is there any alternative to check_markup function for twig?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like something you could do in a preprocess function and create that variable. At that level, you can use [check_markup](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21filter%21filter.module/function/check_markup/8.2.x) to check it.

Be sure to see the two notes on the docs page:

> Note: Because filters can inject JavaScript or execute PHP code,
>   security is vital here. When a user supplies a text format, you should
>   validate it using $format->access() before accepting/using it. This is
>   normally done in the validation stage of the Form API. You should for
>   example never make a preview of content in a disallowed format.
>
> Note: this function should only be used when filtering text for use
>   elsewhere than on a rendered HTML page. If this is part of a HTML
>   page, then a renderable array with a #type 'processed_text' element
>   should be used instead of this, because that will allow cacheability
>   metadata to be set and bubbled up and attachments to be associated
>   (assets, placeholders, etc.). In other words: if you are presenting
>   the filtered text in a HTML page, the only way this will be presented
>   correctly, is by using the 'processed_text' element.

Here is a [similar question/answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/139107/57) (albeit from 2014) that may still apply.